# Application of Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of nonnegative measurable functions on $E$ that converges pointwise on $E$ to $f$.  Suppose $f_n \leq f$ on $E$ for each $n$.  Show that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_E f_n=\int_E f$

This can almost use the Monotone Convergence Theorem, but the sequence is nonnegative.  Can I just choose a subsequence, $\{f_{n_k}\}$ of $\{f_n\}$ that is increasing or is there a way to construct an increasing sequence.?

Comment: There *is* a way to construct an increasing sequence. As a hint, I suggest using a simple construction to define a sequence $g_m$ of nonnegative functions with the following properties: (1) $g_m$ is an increasing sequence, (2) $g_m$ converges to $f$ pointwise, and (3) $g_m$ depends only on the functions $f_n$ for $n\geq m$. If you've constructed the $g_m$ in the right way, what you want to show follows from the monotone convergence theorem applied to the $g_m$.

Comment: But What gurantees that  $lim∫f^{(n)}=lim∫g^{(n)}$

Comment: @Amr: This will follow from the construction of the $g_m$. Maybe I should make that more clear: I'm not claiming that any $g_m$ satisfying (1),(2), and (3) will solve the problem. I have a specific (and simple) construction in mind.

Comment: Emm. OK. I think you meant $g^{(n)}$ =inf{$f^{(n)},f^{(n+1)},...$}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $g_n = \inf_{m \geq n} f_m$. Then the $g_n$ are increasing to $f$ pointwise and $g_n \leq f_n \leq f$. Apply MCT.